# Error in latex, No Bounding box on pdf figure

Tags: graphics, compiling, texshop

I am trying to compile a document on TeXShop (on a mac). I get an error when I insert a picture from a pdf file. I get the error that `bounding box cannot be determined`. 
I looked at other answers. Somebody suggested to compile pdfLatex instead of Latex, but on TexShop I do not see how to do it.

I also tried to fix a bounding box on LaTeX, as in the following:

```
\includegraphics[width=1\columnwidth][bb=0 0 100 100]{nameFileFigure}
```

but it does not work.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: At the top of the TeXShop Window, there are several dropdown menus. One of them (the second from the left) states “LaTeX” and can be changed to “pdflatexmk”. That's what you want to try, if you include a pdf. You could also change your PDF into an eps, if you really want to work with LaTeX further on.

Comment: The syntax for includegraphics has only one optional argument, different options should be separated by commas: `\includegraphics[width=1\columnwidth,bb=0 0 100 100]{nameFileFigure}`

Answer (score 6):

In TeXShop, the Typeset menu includes a line `Pdftex`.  Make sure that is ticked to run `pdflatex` instead of `latex`.

[image: Screen shot]

If you wish to supply a bounding box explicitly to an `\includegraphics` command whilst specifying the width the syntax is

```
\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewdith,bb=0 0 100 100]{figurefile}
```

with options one set of square brackets and separated by commas.

Answer (score 0):

I encount this error for many times. And find a simple solution for me:
just add option `dvipdfmx` to package `graphicx`

like this:
`\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{outline}`

If use beamer, above will cause clash error. This can be solved by adding

`\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipdfmx}{graphicx}`

to the top of the tex file.